# Find out the real path of a file from a SUBST drive

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, shell-script, subst

Is it possible to find the real location of a file, knowing its location on a drive created with `subst`? Example:

```
> subst d: c:\dir\
> real_path "c:\file"
c:\file
> real_path "d:\file"
c:\dir\file
```

Comment: Does running just `subst` tell you?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator parsing the output of `subst` is indeed possible, but I hoped to find a simpler way.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this because my local Python package has installed using both paths: easy-install.pth has the "real path", while <module>.egg-link has the subst path.